# Include folium in bokeh tabs

Tags: python, bokeh, folium

I would like to add a folium map to a bokeh tab.
Is it possible?

When I try i have an error like: expected an instance of type LayoutDOM, got folium of type map.

Otherwise is there another way to do chart in python with map and include it in tab?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh has its own set of objects to represent the built-in widgets that it can display. Only these Bokeh objects can go inside Bokeh layouts like tab panes. However, one of the available widgets is [`Div`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div), which let you put an HTML div with arbitrary content inside a Bokeh layout e.g.

```
div = Div(text="whatever HTML code you want")

layout = column(plot, div)
```

So you could put the raw HTML for a map as the content for one of these `Div` objects.